# Why does this accept invalid input?

Tags: c

I have a triangle program in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// A function which decides the type of the triangle and prints it
void checkTriangle(int s1, int s2,int s3)
{
    // Check the values whether it is triangle or not.
    if ((s1 + s2 > s3 && s1 +  s3 > s2 && s2 + s3 > s1) && (s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0))
    {
        // Deciding type of triangle according to given input.
        if (s1 == s2 && s2 == s3)
            printf("EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE");
        else if (s1 == s2 || s2 == s3 || s1 == s3)
            printf("ISOSCELES TRIANGLE\n");
        else
            printf("SCALENE TRIANGLE \n");
    }
    else
        printf("\nTriangle could not be formed.");
}

int main(void)
{
    // Initializing variables
    int a,b,c;

    // Getting input from user
    printf("Please enter the sides of triangle");

    printf("\nPlease enter side 1:");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("Please enter side 2:");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    printf("Please enter side 3:");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    // Calling function in order to print type of the triangle.
    checkTriangle(a,b,c);
}
```

When the input is:

```
7b
```

it gives an error, which is what I want, but when I entered the data like this:

```
7
7
7b
```

it ignores 'b' and take 7 as an integer — but why? How can I prevent this?

What I want to do is give an error also for

```
7
7
7b
```

Comment: you are processing `int` then why are you adding a hex part ?

Comment: How does three integers determine a triangle?  (Why not three coordinates?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to detect an error with the user's input, such as a line not being a valid decimal integer, then you could do the following:

- Read the input into a buffer using `fgets(buffer, size, stdin)`
- Use `strtoul(buffer, &endptr, 10)` to parse the buffer as a decimal integer (base **10**), where `endptr` is a `char*`
- `endptr` will point to the first invalid character in `buffer`, ie. the character after the last one which was successfully parsed
- Now if `*endptr == '\0'`, ie. `endptr` points to the end of `buffer`, the *whole* string was parsed as a valid decimal integer

Comment: +1: The general outline is certainly correct. Note that `fgets()` keeps the newline, so unless you strip it, `endptr` is likely to point to the newline (or perhaps an innocent space after the number). The return values from `strtoul()` or `strtol()` should be analyzed to ensure that it is a valid `int` (for systems where `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)`, in particular. If you use `strtoul()`, you have to worry about values with the high order bit set; if you use `strtol()`, you have to worry about negative values (which also have the high order bit set, of course). See my answer. Note `errno` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah I should've mentioned that `fgets` stores the newline. And yeah the OP should interchange `strtoul` with `strtol` depending on whether he wants negative values to be included.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want each number on a separate line of input, and for the whole of the line to be valid number or space, then you probably need to forget `scanf()` and family and use `fgets()` and `strtol()` instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

static int read_side(void)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)  // EOF
        return -1;
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long result = strtol(buffer, &end, 10);
    if (result < 0 || errno != 0) // Neither errors nor negative numbers are allowed
        return -1;
    if (end == buffer)     // Nothing was convertible
        return -1;
    while (isspace(*end))
        end++;
    if (*end != '\0')      // Non-spaces after the last digit
        return -1;
    if (result > INT_MAX)  // Result too big for `int`
        return -1;
    return result;
}
```

(If you needed to accept any valid `int` value but distinguish errors, then you'd pass in a pointer to the function and return -1 on error or 0 on success, and assign the safe result to the pointer.)

Yes, it really is that fiddly to do the job properly.  And yes, analyzing the result of `strtol()` is as tricky as that; you do have to be very careful.  (And there's an outside chance I've forgotten to check for a detectable error condition.)  And no, I don't think you can do the equivalent job with `scanf()` et al; in particular, the behaviour on overflow with `scanf()` is undefined.

Comment: +1 - It's a great idea to check `errno`, especially if `ERANGE` is being set.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` accepts only integer. try with `%x` in scanf() for hex-decimal input.

Better you can get input as string then check using `isnumeric()` else use `scanf("%[^\n]s", word)` like @mou suggested.

Comment: i simply take the input as double .p . It does not accept hex.

Comment: @mertmetin: Your code takes the input as a decimal integer, not as a double.  You're right that it does not accept hex.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use scanf or do scanf("%[^\n]s", word); Or  use someting like get()
also put d or x at the end of my example not s for string :P

Comment: is this a bug or a know issue .d

Comment: This is not really a bug I think they wanted that I don't really know but you must know that to go foward in C

Comment: Note that a scan-set conversion specification ends with the close square bracket.  The `s` in your example is not wanted, though it is undetectable with a single `scanf()` call whether the `s` was matched or not (with the given format string).  `get()` is not a standard function; if you're thinking of `gets()`, don't (it is deadly); if you're thinking of `fgets()`, you're more nearly on track.  Putting `d` or `x` at the end of your string would be as bad as the `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input into a string buffer. Parse the string to extract numeric values be of any kind one by one.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the correct way to do it, but there are a lot of steps that are not fully specified in your answer.