# C Trying to check for invalid input

Tags: c, input, scanf, atoi

I'm using `scanf("%s", u);` so I take a string. I can take the characters `q`, `c`, `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`, `%`, `^`, `=`, and integers, but for everything else I want my program to display an error message. How would I know if it's any other character, because if they put anything other than those it will go into an if statement that assumes it's an integer in a string and `atoi()` it which then equals 0 and spoils things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [**scanf**](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html) format specifier to ensure that it stops accepting input the moment it encounters one of the invalid characters.
**%[...]**

> It allows you to specify a set of characters to be stored away (likely
> in an array of chars). Conversion stops when a character that is not
> in the set is matched. For example, %[0-9] means "match all numbers
> zero through nine." And %[AD-G34] means "match A, D through G, 3, or
> 4".
>
> You can tell scanf() to match characters that are not in the set
> by putting a caret (^) directly after the %[ and following it with the
> set, like this: %[^A-C], which means "match all characters that are
> not A through C."

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `scanf()` is the wrong tool for this job.  You should probably consider `fgets()` (or an equivalent such as `readline()` from POSIX 2008).  This will read a whole line into memory.  You can then parse the string, possibly using `sscanf()`, possibly some other 'tokenizing' mechanism that recognizes valid tokens (sequences of one or more characters) and errors.

See the code at [Why does this accept invalid input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889612/why-does-this-accept-invalid-input/12889800#12889800) for an example of how to read one number per input line.  You'd want to adapt that to your purposes; it is not quite appropriate as it stands, but it is a good starting point for the number parsing.  Note too that `atoi()` does no error detection; it is only suitable for very benign environment (such as the one you're probably working in).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to just always scan a string and loop trough it and check for the conditions you want and if it don't pass you send the error message, else you use it. I believe that would be the most trivial way since the input is always chars.